# Laravel join in HasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three models:

EmailTemplate
EmailSend
Attendee

An EmailSend references both an Attendee and an EmailTemplate:

```
class EmailSend extends MyBaseModel {
    ...
    public function attendee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Modals\Attendee::class);
    }
    
    public function template()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Modals\EmailTemplate::class);
    }
    ...
}
```

and associated belongsTo relationships defined in the other direction.

A hasManyThrough relationship between EmailTemplate and Attendee doesn't really make sense so I've not defined that.

My issue is that I want to make a HasMany relationship between EmailTemplate and EmailSend, where the referenced Attendee's 'is_cancelled' field is 0

I currently have this:

```
class EmailTemplate extends MyBaseModel {
    ...
    public function sends()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\EmailSend::class)
                    ->join('attendees', 'email_sends.attendee_id', '=', 'attendees.id')
                    ->where('attendees.is_cancelled', 0);
    }
    ...
}
```

which works, but is there a nicer way to do the join, which uses the existing defined relationships, rather than having to reference table names directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `whereHas` method instead of `join`, but please be aware that `whereHas` queries are generally slower compared to `join` queries because `whereHas` creates a exists query to fetch the results

Answer (score 0):

You can use belongsToMany and  the email_sends table works as a pivot table then the sends table will be same as below

```
public function sends()
{
       return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Modals\Attendee::class,"email_sends");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a whereHas clause to achieve this without using direct joins:

```
public function sends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\EmailSend::class)
                ->whereHas('attendee', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('is_cancelled', 0);
                });
}
```